# Are these sentences grammatically correct? "Climbing in winter can't be safe." "Can climbing in winter be dangerous?"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I'm a Japanese learner of English.
I have some questions about the usage of an auxiliary verb "can."

I think the following two sentences are grammatically correct.

> Climbing in winter can be dangerous.
> Your tomorrow's climbing can't be safe.

However, I'm not sure if the following two sentences are also correct.

> Climbing in winter can't be safe.
> Can climbing in winter be dangerous?

`supplementary explanation`

In a dictionary, I learned about "can" that expresses possibility (not ability or permission) as follows:

---

In **positive** sentences, "can" expresses **general** possibility, that is, possibility that a thing happens **irregularly several times**, and "can" isn't able to express **specific** possibility, that is, possibility that a thing happens **specifically only once**.

For example, the next sentence is **not** correct.

> It can rain tomorrow.

In contrast, the following sentence is correct.

> It may rain tomorrow.

Also, in **negative** sentences and **interrogative** sentences, "can" expresses **specific** possibility.

---

In the dictionary, there isn't a explanation of whether "can" in **negative** sentences and **interrogative** sentences is able to express **general** possibility.
So I post this question.
I think possibility that climbing in winter is safe/dangerous is **general**, that is, it happens **irregularly several times**.

Comment: What are your concerns exactly?

Comment: I trust you realise that the assertion (1) ***X can be dangerous*** carries nowhere near the same meaning as (2) ***X can't be safe***. If not, you need to look into that more closely.

Comment: Indeed, it's rare to say that something "can't be safe" with the deontic meaning of "can": it implies that "There is no way to may that safe".

Comment: I made a supplementary explanation. I'd appreciate it if you would read it.

Answer (score 1):

> Climbing in winter can be dangerous. Your tomorrow's climbing can't be safe.

The second sentence is at least unidiomatic, and arguably wrong. I can't think of a context in which "Your tomorrow's {activity}" would be natural to a fluent speaker.  In fact I am not quite sure of the4 intended meaning here.  Possible rewrites would include:

> - Climbing in winter can be dangerous. Your planned climb tomorrow would not be safe.
> - Climbing in winter can be dangerous. Your climbing tomorrow cannot (must not) be **un**safe.
> - Climbing in winter can be dangerous. I can't imagine that it would be safe fro you to climb tomorrow.

---

The two sentences:

> Climbing in winter can't be safe. Can climbing in winter be dangerous?

...are both grammatically valid and each sounds natural. They don't fit well in the same statement because their meanings are opposed, of course.

---

The sentence:

> It can rain tomorrow.

...is correct if it is expressing physical possibility. For example:

> The monsoon season is almost here. It can rain tomorrow.

This would be more naturally expressed as "it **could** rain tomorrow", but I think the form with "can" will be used in some cases.  Certainly one might write:

> The rainy season usually arrives in July, but it can rain in June

Answer (score 0):

All of your example sentences are grammatically correct, apart from

> "Your tomorrow's climbing can't be safe."

This is standard usage of "can" just with a negative attached, but I would use "Your climbing tomorrow can't be safe." as tomorrow is abstract and you cannot possess it. Your understanding of "can" is perfect however.

Comment: "The climb you plan for tomorrow can't be done safely."

Comment: i read "can't be safe" as "Blimey! that can't be safe!" i.e. hyperbole

Comment: For example, is the following sentences also correct? "For old people, climbing in winter can't be safe." "For old people, can climbing in winter be dangerous?"

Comment: "Tomorrow" can be used in a possessive form: "Tomorrow's weather will be sunny" but "Your tomorrow's climbing" is defiantly not idiomatic, indeed I would label it incorrect. @Aya